# How to receive and store keywords from JSON

Tags: c#, json

I'm working on a currency app. I've found an API that delivers information on what currencies are available. To get that info, I need to hit an endpoint and the result looks

```
{
  "success": true,
  "symbols": {
    "AED": "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
    "AFN": "Afghan Afghani",
    "ALL": "Albanian Lek",
    "AMD": "Armenian Dram",
    [...]
    }
}
```

My class to get this JSON looks like this:

```
 public class SymbolsResult
    {
        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public string Symbols { get; set; }
    }
```

But as you see, the result is received as a string. Then, I need to rework it and my idea was to rework it into a Dictionary in an awful way...

```
SymbolsResult x = jsonDeserializer.Deserialize<SymbolsResult>(response);
            Dictionary<string, string> symbols = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            var strings = x.Symbols.Split(new char[] { ',' });
            foreach(string s in strings)
            {
                string ss = s.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Replace(",", "").Replace("\\", "");
                var sss = ss.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                symbols.Add(sss[0], sss[1]);
            }
            return symbols;
```

Do you have any idea how I can get those results? I just need a hint :)

Comment: Make `Symbols` itself a `Dictionary<string, string>` and the `JsonDeserializer` will do all the work for you

Comment: Holy sh** ! I thought about this, but I was thinking it won't work automatically. But it works !

Comment: FYI you can deserialize any JSON to `Dictionary<string, JsonObject>`, as that's basically what JSON is